# Cutoff length for vdW correction in DFT calculation

Tags: density-functional-theory, mathematical-modeling, dispersion-correction, derivations

In classical MD simulations of lattice structures, whenever we are trying to incorporate vdW corrections to the atomic force calculation, we need to set up cutoff length beyond which the vdW correction is not considered to keep the computational cost manageable. As a result, **the classical simulation requires reasonably large supercell(usually with its dimensions twice as long as the cutoff length) to capture vdW interactions**.

When it comes to DFT calculations, however, the cutoff lengths for nonlocal vdW corrections, such as the rVV10 functional, are not explicitly set in DFT software like Quantum ESPRESSO. It is also common practice to use **primitive cells in DFT calculations along with nonlocal vdW functionals**. By looking at the formalism of the rVV10 vdW correction, the integration of the functional is clearly performed within a volume,
$$
E_{c}^{n l}=\frac{\hbar}{2} \iint n(\mathbf{r}) \Phi\left(n, n^{\prime},|\nabla n|,\left|\nabla n^{\prime}\right|,\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^{\prime}\right|\right) n\left(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}\right) d \mathbf{r} d \mathbf{r}^{\prime},\tag{1}
$$
where $n(\mathbf{r})$ is the charge density at location of $\mathbf{r}$. So my question is **what are the lower and upper limits for Eq. (1), and how do we derive them?**

To attack this question, I tried to understand Eq.(1) in terms of its Fourier transform,
$$
E_{c}^{n l}=\frac{\hbar}{2} \Omega \sum_{i j} \sum_{\mathbf{G}} \tilde{\theta}_{i}^{*}(\mathbf{G}) \tilde{\Phi}^{\mathrm{rVV} 10}\left(q_{i}, q_{j},|\mathbf{G}|\right) \tilde{\theta}_{j}(\mathbf{G}),\tag{2}
$$
where $\tilde{\Phi}^{\mathrm{rVV} 10}\left(q_{i}, q_{j},|\mathbf{G}|\right)$ are the Fourier transforms of the rVV10 kernel evaluated on a bidimensional grid of $q$ values, and $\tilde{\theta}_{i}$ are the Fourier transforms of $\theta_{i}$ introduced in the rVV10 paper [here](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.87.041108). But this left me with more questions than answers. I have a feeling that I might be pursuing the answer in a wrong line of thinking, so any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: +10. Nice first question! I see you've been here for 8 months but I'm meeting you for the first time now, so welcome to our new community and thank you very much for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future, and thanks also for formatting yoru question so nicely, including equation number labels!!! Here's a related question which might interest you: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/63/5

Comment: I have commented out your second question: "how is the wavevector in the reciprocal space $\mathbf{G}$ is related to the cutoff length of vdW correction?", which I encourage you to ask as a separate question if you need that!

Comment: Have you had any luck with this since November?

Comment: unfortunately no... this whole vdW correction, to a large extent, is still mysterious to me... Thanks for asking tho@NikeDattani

Comment: I'm just checking in again, any luck with this? Are you still working on it?

Comment: Nope... vdW is no longer part of my life now...

Comment: The question can be reopened if it becomes part of your life again!

Comment: I would vote to keep it open, it is a good and detailed question in any case

Comment: @Lonitch I think pg 20 in https://www.cp2k.org/_media/events:2015_cecam_tutorial:ling_vdw.pdf might be relevant (at least for cp2k). I also had trouble on deciding a standard cutoff value so my case, I simply put the "factor" as -1.

Comment: @mykd I know this file for quite some time now, but thx for your comments anyway. It seems to me in cp2k you need to specify the cutoff(in a unit of energy?) of the reciprocal lattice, which is inversely proportional to the cutoff length in real space. I guess essentially I only care about how to decide such a cutoff given a lattice of any type/size.

Comment: So the plane wave cutoff in QM calculations using periodic cell depend largely on two factors 1) Type of atoms 2) density functional used. For example in cp2k, a cutoff of 280 Rydberg is recommended for water (compared to 60-90 Ryd in Quantum Espresso) for simple GGAs like BLYP, PBE but can go upto 800-1200 Ryd for meta-GGAs like M06-L. I think you need to reconsider r-VV10 as density functional rather than a simple correction as DFT-Dn family

Comment: If you are having trouble reconciling the cutoff in real and reciprocal space, check out https://www.theochem.ru.nl/files/local/prb-45-13891-1992.pdf, particularly section III. You also might need to check out further details of Ewald summation to fully get the cutoff in real and reciprocal space.

Comment: @mykd Thanks for ur advice. I apologize if my comment confuses you, but I didn't have problems finding the cutoff in the reciprocal space. In QE, it largely depends on types of ur pseudo-potentials. PBE+rVV10 is known to be a cheap and decent option when calculating the electrochemical properties of energy storage material. Not a big fan of semi-empirical vdW methods because of (a) slow convergence in MD simulation, and b) significant lattice energy change when increasing the cutoff length. OP is, however, seeking to understand the rVV10 formalism by drawing mathematical insights...

Comment: Good discussion here. Just a reminder that we prefer not to create new chat, so don't click the prompt to move to chat if the discussion goes long. Just ping me and I can move the comments to an existing room if you want to continue in chat.

Comment: Just in case anyone is confused about why this question was closed as abandoned (because it took me a while to figure it out, since the OP responded to all comments here): The question is about a topic on which the OP [no longer works](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/cutoff-length-for-vdw-correction-in-dft-calculation#comment22048_7139) and we said that it can be re-opened if the OP wants. However, we would like to prioritize our resources on questions that students or researchers truly need to solve as part of their work.